# Missing dependency while testing

Tags: unit-testing, nestjs, ts-jest

I'm making an app using NestJS. Everything works fine, but I got stuck while making the unit tests.
To query my database, I'm using Prisma. Therefore, I created the following **PrismaModule**:

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from './prisma.service';
import { AbstractPrismaService } from './abstract-prisma.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  providers: [{
    provide: AbstractPrismaService,
    useClass: PrismaService
  }],
  exports: [AbstractPrismaService]
})
export class PrismaModule {}
```

It is global and provides the **AbstractPrismaService**, using the **PrismaService** class. Here are the details of the implementations:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';


export abstract class AbstractPrismaService extends PrismaClient {
    //TODO: set the return type
  abstract cleanDb();
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { AbstractPrismaService } from './abstract-prisma.service';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends AbstractPrismaService {
    constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
        super({
            datasources: {
                db: {
                    url: configService.get('DATABASE_URL'),
                },
            },
        });
    }

    cleanDb(): void {
        //TODO: implement
    }
}
```

Now, I'm using the **AbstractPrismaService** as a dependency in the **BookService**:

```
import { HttpException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AbstracBookService } from './abstract-book.service';
import { AbstractPrismaService } from 'src/prisma/abstract-prisma.service';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { BookCreationResponseDto,BookCreationDto } from './book-dtos';
import { PrismaClientKnownRequestError } from '@prisma/client/runtime';

@Injectable()
export class BookService implements AbstracBookService {
    constructor(private readonly prisma: AbstractPrismaService) {}
    
    async createBook(book:BookCreationDto):Promise<BookCreationResponseDto> {
        const data = {
            bookId: uuidv4(),
            bookTitle: book.title,
            coverUrl: book.coverUrl,
            bookStatus:'active'
        };

        
        try {        
            const bookId:BookCreationResponseDto = await this.prisma.book.create({
                    data:data,
                    select:{
                        bookId:true
                    }
                });

            return bookId;
        }catch (error:PrismaClientKnownRequestError | any) {
            throw this.createError(error.code || 'UNKNOWN_ERROR');
        }

    }

    private createError(erroCode:string):HttpException{
        if (erroCode === 'P2002') {
            return new HttpException('Book already exists', 409);
        }
        return new HttpException('Internal server error', 500)
    }
}
```

```
import { BookCreationDto,BookCreationResponseDto } from "./book-dtos";


export abstract class AbstracBookService{
    abstract  createBook(book: BookCreationDto):Promise<BookCreationResponseDto>;
}
```

The problem begins when I try to test the **BookService**, because is not defined as it is not able to find the **AbstractPrismaService**.

Here is the test file:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { BookService } from '../book.service';
import { AbstracBookService } from '../abstract-book.service';

describe('BookService', () => {
  let service: AbstracBookService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [{
        provide: AbstracBookService,
        useClass: BookService
      }],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<AbstracBookService>(AbstracBookService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Here is the error:

```
    Cannot find module 'src/prisma/abstract-prisma.service' from 'book/book.service.ts'

    Require stack:
      book/book.service.ts
      book/test/book.service.spec.ts

      1 | import { HttpException, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
      2 | import { AbstracBookService } from './abstract-book.service';
    > 3 | import { AbstractPrismaService } from 'src/prisma/abstract-prisma.service';
        | ^
      4 | import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
      5 | import { BookCreationResponseDto,BookCreationDto } from './book-dtos';
      6 | import { PrismaClientKnownRequestError } from '@prisma/client/runtime';
```

Here is the project distribution:

```
src
|
|_ _ prisma _ _ abstract-prisma.service.ts
|          |
|          |_ _ prisma.service.ts
|          |
|          |_ _ prisma.module.ts
|
|
|
|_ _ book _ _ abstract-book.service.ts
           |
           |_ _ book.service.ts
           |
           |_ _ book.module.ts
           |
           |
           |
           |_ _ tests
           |       |
           |       |
           |       |_ _ stubs
           |                |
           |                |_ _ book.stub.ts
           |
           |
           |_ _ __mocks__
```

I want the BookService to pass the "to be defined test" by mocking all of its dependencies.

What I have tried:

Import the PrismaModule while providing the AbstractPrismaService mock with a mock PrismaService:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { BookService } from '../book.service';
import { AbstracBookService } from '../abstract-book.service';
import { AbstractPrismaService } from 'src/prisma/abstract-prisma.service';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma/prisma.service';
import { PrismaModule } from 'src/prisma/prisma.module';

jest.mock('src/prisma/abstract-prisma.service');
jest.mock('src/prisma/prisma.service');


describe('BookService', () => {
  let service: AbstracBookService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [PrismaModule],
      providers: [{
        provide: AbstracBookService,
        useClass: BookService
      },{
        provide: AbstractPrismaService,
        useClass: PrismaService
      }
      ]
    }).compile();


    service = module.get<AbstracBookService>(AbstracBookService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
ed', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

The root directory would change:

```
src
|
|_ _ prisma _ _ abstract-prisma.service.ts
|          |
|          |_ _ prisma.service.ts
|          |
|          |_ _ prisma.module.ts
|
|
|
|_ _ book _ _ abstract-book.service.ts
           |
           |_ _ book.service.ts
           |
           |_ _ book.module.ts
           |
           |
           |
           |_ _ tests
           |       |
           |       |
           |       |_ _ stubs
           |                |
           |                |_ _ book.stub.ts
           |
           |
           |_ _ __mocks__
                         |
                         |
                         |
                         |_ _ prismaMock.service.ts
                         |
                         |
                         |_ _ abstract-prisma.service.ts
```

How the mock service looks like:

```
import { AbstractPrismaService } from "./abstract-prisma.service";

export class PrismaService extends AbstractPrismaService {

    async cleanDb() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

How the abstract service mock looks like:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

export abstract class AbstractPrismaService extends PrismaClient {
    //TODO: set the return type
  abstract cleanDb();
}
```

The error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'src/prisma/abstract-prisma.service' from 'book/test/book.service.spec.ts'

       6 | import { PrismaModule } from 'src/prisma/prisma.module';
       7 |
    >  8 | jest.mock('src/prisma/abstract-prisma.service');
         |      ^
       9 | jest.mock('src/prisma/prisma.service');
```

I am a beginner. Maybe I'm taking a naive approach. But, I just do not know how to make the AbstractPrismaService available for the test. I would appreciate some help.

If you need more context, just tell me.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Jest doesn't know how to interpret absolute (`src/`) imports by default, you have to use the [`moduleNameMapper` jest config option](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) to set the correct path for implementation